# Ruby on Rails: text filed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textfield

I have a code where a user can select a specific file to be deleted or analyzed.

```
 <% if @files%>    
    <%= form_tag what_to_do_files_path, method: :get do %>
    <%= submit_tag "Delete selected", :name => 'delete' %>
    <%= submit_tag "Analyse", :name => 'analyse' %>
      <% @files.each do |file| %>
        <% if (file.analyzed=="no") %>
            <p><td> <%= check_box_tag "files[]", file.id %></td><%= file.name %></p>       

        <% else %>      

        <div class="my_profile_info">     
        <p><td> <%= check_box_tag "files[]", file.id %></td> <%= file.name %></p>        

        <td class="Info">
        <a href="<%=file.info%>" target ="_blank" class= "btn btn-mini btn-info">Info</a>  
        </td>  

         </div>

        <% end %>
      <%end%>
    <%end%> 
    <%else%>
    <%end%>
```

I need to be able to give a name to every analysis.
For example: user selects 3 files, enters a name in the text field "Analysis of annual profit" and clicks on the button "Analyse".
The name "Analysis of the annual profit" and the names of the files that were selected  have to be saved into the table group_analysis.
I have tried something like this after submit_tag "Analyse":

```
<%= form_for @groupanalysis do |f| %>
      <div class="field_label">
        <%= f.label :group_name, "Type group name hier" %>
      </div>

  <br class="clear" />
  <br />

<% end %>
```

but it tells me `undefined method model name`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to take a step back and think of how this form represents the model that you're trying to create or update. Generally speaking the first argument to `form_for` and `form_tag` is an object and symbol, respectively, which represent the model that you're working with. The form fields map to each attribute of the object.

According to conventions and/or the `:url` argument, this will get routed to the appropriate controller and call an action according to the HTTP verb (again, part of many conventions in rails).

Going back to your code examples, you are using the `form_tag` helper incorrectly and the example using `form_for` may not be the right implementation. For example you're just displaying a label, with no input nor submit.

I hate to just post a link here and just tell you to read the docs, but in this case I think this is the best first step.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for